# Problemas para hacer encoding a un arrey de bytes y meterlo a un MemoryStrem

Tags: c#

Hola buenos dias estoy obteniendo la informacion desde un objeto Message obteniendo el body y lo almaceno en un arreglo de bytes, ya que esa informacion la pasaré a un datatable pero uno de los encabezados tiene una "ú" y al hacer la conversión de CSV a DataTable me sale la ú como un ⧫ y adentro un signo de interrogacion "?" como puedo hacer el Encoding al MemoryStream o al arreglo de Bytes? intente convirtiendo los bytes a string y luego puse el encoding pero no lo hace bien, me lo retorna aun como string, adjunto mi código y mi metodo:

```
 byte[] fileData = message.MessagePart.MessageParts[j].Body;
 Stream str = new MemoryStream(fileData);

 DataTable dtResultComsuption = ConvertCSVtoDataTable(str);




private DataTable ConvertCSVtoDataTable(Stream strFilePath)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(strFilePath))
    {
        string[] headers = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
        foreach (string header in headers)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(header.Replace("\"","").Replace("\r","").Replace("\n",""));
        }
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            string[] rows = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
                {
                    dr[i] = rows[i];
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                int iii=dt.Rows.Count;
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
    }
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: El constructor de StreamReader tiene una sobrecarga donde le puedes especificar el encoding. Averigua cual es el encoding y pásaselo como parámetro al constructor, y si no, prueba con los encodings más usuales hasta que aciertes. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=net-7.0

Comment: Por cierto, tu manejo de excepciones es incorrecto. No debes lanzar una nueva excepción, porque pierdes información de la pila de llamadas. En vez de `throw new Exception(ex.Message)`, deberías poner simplemente `throw` lo cual relanza la excepción original sin perder ninguna información orginal del error

Comment: Por otra parte tu parseo del csv es de "andar por casa" y puede fallar si los campos del csv tienen comillas o comas dentro. Es mucho mejor usar un parseador más "profesional" como CsvHelper https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper. Mira realmente como es el formato csv estándar https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180

Comment: Por último comentar que la nomenclatura de las variables y parámetros que usas es confuso. El nombre del parámetro `strFilePath` sugiere que el contenido del parámetro es una cadena de carateres que contiene la ruta a un archivo, cuando en realidad es un `Stream`, un mejor nombre sería por ejemplo `sourceStream`. La variable `rows` es un array de strings cuyo contenido son los valores de los campos de un registro del csv, por tanto no debería llamarse `rows` sino `fields`

Comment: Se ha solucionado en problema, solo me faltaba poner el Encoding al StreamReader, gracias